# What is "Pre-build with user-provided Hadoop" package

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to set up spark, but I can't know the meaning of user-provided Hadoop. 
Why "Choose a package type" menu say "**with** user-provided Hadoop" ,but "Download Spark" menu say "spark-1.6.0-bin-**without**-hadoop.tgz".

I was very confused whether hadoop is needed or not needed.

[image]

Comment: I found [Using Spark's "Hadoop Free" Build](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html) explain well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This option means that you must provide your hadoop jars, assuming it is installed on your cluster

Comment: refer to this page for more details: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/hadoop-provided.html